# I have problem with updating profile photo in Django

Tags: python, django, photo, user-profile

I am trying to update Profile photo with Django

According to yt tutorials I created form for updating photo:

```
class UserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User_Model
        fields = ["profile_photo"]
```

And this is my class to Change photo in views:

```
class UpdatePhoto(TemplateView):
    template_name = "Messenger/update_photo.html"
    profile_form = UserProfileForm

    def post(self, response):
        data = response.POST
        file_data = response.FILES
        profile_form = UserProfileForm(data, file_data, instance=response.user.profile)
        if profile_form.is_valid():
            profile_form.save()
            return redirect("/")
        print("rere")
        context = self.get_context_data(profile_form=profile_form)
        return self.render_to_response(context)
```

My Model:

```
class User_Model(models.Model):
user = models.OneToOneField(
    User, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="profile"
)
profile_photo = models.ImageField(
    upload_to="images/", default="default_photo.jpg", null=True, blank=True
)
chats = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="chats", blank=True)
blocked_list = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="blocked_list", blank=True)
```

I was trying with and without 'response.POST', result was the same, it does not update. However when I try to print 'file_data' I get something like this:

```
<MultiValueDict: {'Browser': [<InMemoryUploadedFile: thumb.jpg (image/jpeg)>]}>
```

Main Settings.py:

```
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = "static/"

MEDIA_URL = "/media/"

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media")

STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),)
# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = "django.db.models.BigAutoField"
```

And main urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
    path("", include("Messenger.urls")),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

App urls:

```
from django.urls import path
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path(
        "",
        login_required(views.Chat_list_Usernames.as_view(), login_url="/login"),
        name="home",
    ),
    path(
        "change_status/",
        login_required(views.change_status, login_url="/login"),
        name="change_status",
    ),
    path("login/", views.login_page, name="login_page"),
    path(
        "logout/", login_required(views.logout_user, login_url="/login"), name="logout"
    ),
    path("register/", views.register_page, name="register_page"),
    path(
        "update_photo/",
        login_required(views.UpdatePhoto.as_view(), login_url="/login"),
        name="update_photo",
    ),
    path(
        "change_password/",
        login_required(views.ChangePassword.as_view(), login_url="/login"),
        name="change_password",
    ),
    path(
        "send_message/",
        login_required(views.SendMessage.as_view(), login_url="/login"),
        name="send_message",
    ),
]
```

And my template:

```
{% load static %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/update_photo.css'%}">
<div class="main-content">
    <div class="heading">Change</div>
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="photo">
            <div class="button">
                <input id="files" required type="file" name="Browser"
                    accept="image/png, image/jpeg, image/jpg, image/webp">
            </div>
            <div class="buttons">
                <div class="button">
                    <a href="{% url 'home'%}"><input type="button" name="Back" , value="Back"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="button">
                    <input type="submit" name="Change" , value="Change">
                </div>
            </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Also I need to mention that I can update photo though admin panel but it's how this should work .

I Have no idea what have I done wrong and how to make it work right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [`UpdateView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#updateview) instead of `TemplateView` as it only renders a given template, with the context containing parameters captured in the URL.